# Is there a non-InfoPath alternative to Google Forms?

Tags: 2010, infopath

Is there a non-InfoPath alternative to Google Forms?

I need a non-InfoPath solution because many of our systems do not have InfoPath installed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use SharePoint lists to support master-detail relationships, which effectively gives you forms: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using SharePoint? SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise edition?

If yes, your users do not need to have InfoPath installed on their machine. All is required is to enable InfoPath Form Services in the Central Administration Web site and in the document library settings specify open forms in browser.

Comment: The only catch is that not all of the functionality that the InfoPath client has can be accomplished in web forms.  It certainly can cover the basics though.

Comment: That is true. What specific functionality you are looking for that is not in Web version? I have always been able to find a workaround. If you are using InfoPath 2010, the client and the Web version are very close in terms of functionality. The other option I see is to create the forms using ASP.NET, but that would involve more development time and cost.

Comment: @HosseinAarabi - I have SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites. Does my version have InfoPath Form Services by default?

Comment: @saumilm - I have not worked with SP 2010 for Internet Sites product. SP 2010 for Internet Sites also has multiple editions, Standard and Enterprise. You will need the Enterprise edition. Reference: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/internetsites/products/Pages/SharePoint.aspx?Product=SharePoint "Publish Microsoft InfoPath forms in SharePoint Server 2010. InfoPath forms can be rendered to users who haven’t installed the program to gather InfoPath information."

Comment: I have SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites Enterprise Edition. So InfoPath forms should work right?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to work with InfoPath Form Services.

Comment: Be advised that InfoPath Forms Services does not work for anonymous access.

Comment: @Mike this blog might help you: http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/infopath-allowing-anonymous-users-to-submit-forms-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 3):

If InfoPath is not an option, an alternative would be Nintex Forms - http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexForms2010.aspx

Comment: Does Nintex forms work in emails?